# YouTube comment and reply listing

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api

I am using YouTube (Google) api (c#).
I am listing comments for a video.
I want to be able to associate a reply with its parent comment for display purposes.
What is the association between comment and reply?

Comment: Nothing so far but I'm going to try Jonny Burger's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If a comment is a reply to another, the `link` array of a comment contains a object with the link to the original comment. It should look like this:

```
{
rel: "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#in-reply-to",
type: "application/atom+xml",
href: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/WRGmlVJD1tE/comments/wiskpP8JKnkb2xWsGKrGwTadVHSGoTIKXeEtJ2PWeCw"
}
```

You have to make another HTTP request, but at least it works :D

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know how this should be done with the dot net api?